# How to change the position of a canvas (not in Android)?

Tags: java, canvas, graphics, translate

This is my code so far:

```
public static void init() {
    Canvas background = new Canvas();
    Canvas mapWindow = new Canvas();
    Frame window = new Frame();

    background.setSize(500,700);
    mapWindow.setSize(500,500);

    background.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
    mapWindow.setBackground(Color.black);
    background.setForeground(Color.white);

    window.add(mapWindow);
    window.add(background);
    window.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    window.setSize(500,700);
    //mapWindow.translate(0,100);
    window.setVisible(true);
}
```

The code that is commented out is the one that I'm having trouble with (I know I'm using the wrong method. I haven't done much with graphics so I'm experimenting.) I'm trying to move the mapWindow canvas so that it starts 100 pixels down instead of at (0,0) on the frame. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?  There's a lot of things wrong here (imo).  You are using the outdated AWT (abstract windowing toolkit).  You should be using Swing...but that doesn't change much of anything here.  Instead of `Canvas`, you should use `JPanel` (or `JComponent`).  Instead of `Frame`, you should use `JFrame`.  Instead of `Applet`, you should use `JApplet`.  There really isn't a way to specify an exact position of a component.  You have to use a `LayoutManager`.  My guess is the `SpringLayout` layout would be your best bet.

Comment: Here's an article on AWT vs. Swing: http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/26970

Comment: You could set `window.setLayout(null);` and then `mapWindow.setBounds(100,0,500,500)`, but I do **NOT** recommend that. You should have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html

Comment: @Jared Man, I wish I had seen your comment earlier! After some more experimentation, I did end up changing it to a JPanel, changing the Frame to a JFrame, and changing the FlowLayout to a BorderLayout to get the look I wanted. But thanks for your help! At least I know now that I'm going in the right direction.

Comment: Just remember, _don't ever extend JFrame!_  Any application you _ever_ make should extend `JPanel` (again, or `JComponent`--I still have yet to understand the difference).  Then your main method is the _exact_ same _every_ time.  Create a `JFrame frame = new JFrame(...)`, then just use `frame.setContentPane(new YourPanel(...))`.  Or, if you want to create an applet, you simply set the `JApplet`'s `ContentPane` in the `init` method the same way (except it will be `this.setContentPane(new YourPanel(...))`).